# Using React and prop-types with CDN

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

Is there any way to make React work with the CDN?  I'm only getting one error message "Cannot find module 'prop-types'" in the file "react.d.ts" in Visual Studio.  I'm using the built-in VS bundler.

### index.html

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
```

### react.d.ts - The error occurs on this line

```
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Comment: Why do you not use bundler ? (webpack/parcel) or CLI (create-react-app) ?

Comment: Do your scripts tags are declare into <header> or <body> ?

Comment: @Kornflexx - Using built-in VS bundler and script tags are in header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add prop-types.d.ts to my project.  That fixed the last error message.